# bash script with sudo privileges

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a script that will run across several hosts with root permissions. I tried the following efforts but cannot see the output in output file. this is not running as well. what changes can be done to run as root and can see output at my local. I am looking to run clean1.sh script.

```
1. cat hostnames.txt
a
b 

2. cat clean1.sh
for server in $(cat /path/hostnames.txt);
do
   echo $server;
   scp /path/cleansubpart.sh rkadam@$server:/tmp/;
   ssh rkadam@"$server" "sudo su - && source /tmp/cleansubpart.sh > /tmp/output.txt 2>&1"
done

3. cat cleansubpart.sh
#!/bin/bash
puppet agent --disable "CM Upgreade"
/etc/init.d/cloudera-scm-agent hard_stop_confirmed
yum remove cloudera-manager-agent cloudera-manager-daemons -y
mount|grep cloudera|cut -f 3 -d ' '|xargs -I {} umount {}
[[ -d /tmp/empty ]] || mkdir /tmp/empty
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data1 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data2 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data3 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data4 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data5 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data6 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data7 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data8 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data9 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data10 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data11 &
rsync -rd --delete /tmp/empty/ /data12 &
wait
rm -rf /srv/* /var/lib/cloudera* /var/run/cloudera* /var/log/cloudera* /var/log/hadoop* /etc/default/cloudera* /etc/cloudera* /etc/hadoop* /opt/cloudera*
puppet agent --enable
puppet agent -tv
```

Comment: You can try `"sudo /tmp/cleansubpart.sh > /tmp/output.txt 2>&1"`, but make sure you have `NOPASSWD` for your user in the `/etc/sudoers` file on each server.

Comment: just running with Sudo doesn't work all commands in cleansubpart.sh

Comment: Try adding `-t` to your `ssh` command to force the allocation of a tty.

Comment: `for server in $(cat /path/hostnames.txt);
do
   echo $server;
   scp /path/cleansubpart.sh rkadam@$server:/tmp/;
   ssh -t rkadam@"$server" "/tmp/cleansubpart.sh > /tmp/output.txt 2>&1";
done`